# Radial gradient center doesn't match span center

Tags: css

I centered radial gradient 200 px from the top and 200 px from the left. The same I did with span witch contains letter "a". But as I see, [gradient center doesn't mach the span center.](http://jsfiddle.net/mindaugo/cyzczvd1/)
Why does it happen?

```
<body>
    <div class="box"><span>a</span></div>
</body>
```

CSS

```
.box {
position:relative;
width: 300px;
height: 300px;
background: -webkit-gradient(radial, 200 200, 20, 200 200, 30,  from(#FCFCFC), to(#CF0C13));
}

span {
position: absolute;
left: 200px;
top: 200px;
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have it correct.

### Problem:

The problem you are seeing is because, the `span` ***starts*** at `X = 200px`  and `Y = 200px`. While the radial gradient sets its ***center*** at that point. This is because of the default font glyph which leaves space for ascenders and descenders. This will change for every font-family you have.

This is visible in this snippet, see the span marked in blue:

```css
.box {
    position: relative;
    width: 300px; height: 300px;
    background: -webkit-radial-gradient(200px 200px, circle, #fcfcfc 10%, #cf0c13 15%, #cf0c13 100%);
}
    
span {
    position: absolute; 
    left: 200px; top: 200px;
    border: 1px solid blue;
}
```

```html
 <div class="box"><span>a</span></div>
```

### Solution:

Just shift the radial origin by `10px` down on `Y` axis.

Like this: `-webkit-radial-gradient(200px 210px....`

***Snippet***:

```css
.box {
    position: relative;
    width: 300px; height: 300px;
    background: -webkit-radial-gradient(200px 210px, circle, #fcfcfc 10%, #cf0c13 15%, #cf0c13 100%);
}
    
span {
    position: absolute; 
    left: 200px; top: 200px;
}
```

```html
 <div class="box"><span>a</span></div>
```

Alternatively, if your `span` contents are going to change, then its better to use the `translate(-50%, -50%)` trick to shift it negatively by half-of its size.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `transform: translate(-50%, -50%)` on the `span` to align it in the center. This way you won't have to worry about the `font-size`.

```css
.box {
  position: relative;
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  background: -webkit-gradient(radial, 200 200, 20, 200 200, 30,  from(#FCFCFC), to(#CF0C13));
}
span {
  position: absolute;
  left: 200px;
  top: 200px;
  font-size: 16px;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

```html
<div class="box"><span>a</span>
</div>
```

---

For the `radial-gradient`, you should use the following syntax.

```
background: -webkit-radial-gradient(200px 200px, #FCFCFC 20px, #CF0C13 30px);
background: -moz-radial-gradient(200px 200px, #FCFCFC 20px, #CF0C13 30px);
background: radial-gradient(200px 200px, #FCFCFC 20px, #CF0C13 30px);
```

Answer (score 1):

In gradient definition you tell where should be the **center** of gradient background. In left/top properties for span you set left top corner of this span.

It means that the gradient center is in the same place as a span's left top corner (You can see that on http://jsfiddle.net/cyzczvd1/4/).

You need to move span a little bit, I prepare you another fiddle:

```
.box {
    position:relative;
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;
    background: -webkit-gradient(radial, 200 200, 20, 200 200, 30,  from(#FCFCFC), to(#CF0C13));
}

span {
    position: absolute;
    left: 200px;
    top: 200px;
    /* 
       added lines below, background to see element borders, size, centering of text and 
       move back - you can set directly left: 180px; top: 180px; and avoid this negative margins 
    */
    background: red;
    display: block; 
    width: 40px; 
    height: 40px;
    margin: -20px 0 0 -20px;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 40px;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/cyzczvd1/3/